# Display error message in HTML from Webseal

Tags: html, webseal, isam

Hello I have an error page for user when their account gets locked. When I view the source code of page it just contains one line

```
%ERROR%
```

I am trying to understand if this is some kind of string interpolation as I have never seen it done with % sign. The error message that is displayed is [this](https://www.ibm.com/docs/no/samfm/8.0.1?topic=messages-hpdia0306w)

Answer (score 0):

The raw file you are viewing is a response page template.  When that page is presented to the client making the request, the %MACRONAME% values are substituted and the HTML (or JSON) content returned from the web reverse proxy has that substituted text.  Hint, you can further customize the messages to the user by substituting the macro into a javascript variable within the response page template, and then make logic decisions based on that client side javascript code.  For example, you could catch one of the IBM error codes and translate it into saying something like "Account is locked".

More information is available on the macros within the [IBM documentation.](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/sva/10.0.1?topic=modification-macro-resources-customizing-response-pages)